# What is the difference between pip list and pip freeze?

Tags: python, pip

What is the difference between `pip list` and `pip freeze`? Seems them both doing about the same, but formatting is different, what is the use case of each of them? which one is more preferable?

Answer (score 1):

`pip list` shows all installed packages, whereas `pip freeze` shows the ones installed by the user.

Comment: On Linux, this is misleading: both show ALL packages, including those installed by the system's package manager. `pip freeze` omits only setuptools, wheel, pip, distribute, but has an `all` option to include them. See the [documentaion](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/#cmdoption-all).